# Python Cookie Clicker: Auto Click Function?

Tags: python, function, button, user-interface, tkinter

**My Background:**
I have done quite a bit of programming with python, I would say I am not bad at it. I am familiar with most of the modules, OOP programming and stuff. You can check my pastebin profile to see what level I am actually in: www.pastebin.com/u/GameNationRDF/

**The Code:**

```
from tkinter import *
import time

master = Tk()

def uiPrint():
    info()
    print ("")
    print (click)
    blankLine()

def info():
    print ("Double click purchases need 750 clicks!")

info()

click = 0
mult = 1
dcp1 = 0

def blankLine():
    for i in range(20):
        print ("")

def purchaseDoubleClicksCommand():
    global click
    global mult
    if click < 750:
        print ("Not enough clicks!")
        blankLine()
    elif click >= 750:
        mult = mult*2
        click = click - 750
        print ("Double Clicks Purchased!")
        blankLine()

def buttonCommand():
    global click
    global mult
    click += 1*(mult)
    uiPrint()

    if click == 100:
        print ('''Achievement Unlocked: Junior Clicker!
    BONUS 100!''')
        click += 100

    elif click == 400:
        print ('''Achievement Unlocked: Little Ninja Clicks!
    BONUS 200!''')
        click += 300

    elif click == 900:
        print ('''Achievement Unlocked: Legit Ninja!
    DOUBLE CLICKS!''')
        mult = mult * 2

    elif click == 1500:
        print ('''Achievement Unlocked: Click Ninja Master!
    QUAD CLICKS!''')
        mult = mult * 4

    elif click == 3000:
        print ('''Achievement Unlocked:  Jackie Chan Style!
    8 TIMES THE CLICKS!''')

mainClickButton = Button(master, text="Click!", command=buttonCommand)
mainClickButton.pack()

purchaseDoubleClickButton = Button(master, text="Purchase Double Clicks", command = purchaseDoubleClicksCommand)
purchaseDoubleClickButton.pack()


master.title("Clicker! v0.0.6")
master.geometry("%sx%s+%s+%s" % (200,70,512,512))
mainloop()
```

I need a way to be able to add a auto-clicker that would add certain amount of cookies in a given time. I want it to be purchased by a button. I couldnt get it to work though :(

Any help? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [PyUserInput project](https://github.com/SavinaRoja/PyUserInput) looks promising and straightforward:

```
from pymouse import PyMouse
m = PyMouse()
x_dim, y_dim = m.screen_size()
m.click(x_dim/2, y_dim/2, 1)
```

Why do you `import *` by the way? It's bad practice to import more dependencies than needed.
Also if I were you I would move the following section of code:

```
master = ()
info()
click = 0
mult = 1
dcp1 = 0
```

to reside above this line:

```
mainlickButton = Button(master, text="Click!", command=buttoncommand)
```

It's just cleaner to add declarations and functions. It doesn't make a GINORMOUS difference now, but when your file gets bigger and you have a lot of code it will be easier to read.

Comment: Hey thank you so much! I will now get to work on my code, according to your useful suggestions :)